# How to write case when statement to see if sum of 2 values equal?

Tags: sql

I am still learning sql so I apologize if this is easy stuff.

I need the sql code to sum the sales amount and sum the returnamount, and if they equal I want to mark that accountnumber with a 1 to know that it is fully cancelled.

```
i.[status], i.accountnumber,
case when sum(i.saleamount) = sum(r.returnamount) then 1 else 0 end as full_return_flag
from [idtable] i 
join [returntable] r on r.id = i.id


> Account Number Sale Amount  Return Amount   Full_return_flag  Status
> 1                 500              250                    1    Open
> 2                 500             1500                    1    Open
> 3                2000               0                     0    Neutral
> 4                  100              0                     0    Closed
```

Comment: Can you post the data of the 2 tables? And why are you doing a `LEFT JOIN`? I'm not MySQL, but is the `GROUP BY` implied here?

Comment: Your syntax is not MySQL-compatible.  Are you sure that is the database  you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want aggregation with `case` expression :

```
select i.status, i.accountnumber, sum(i.saleamount) as saleamount, sum(r.returnamount) as returnamount,
       (case when sum(i.saleamount - r.returnamount) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Full_return_flag
from idtable] i inner join
     returntable r
     on r.id = t.id
group by i.status, i.accountnumber;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is perfect. But how do you also select i.[status] with the query you wrote??

Comment: @lizfrinko. . . If same account has different status then result may differ. For acurate you need include some sample data & desired result in question.

Comment: I added status as a column in my question. There can only be one status per account.

Comment: @lizfrinko. . . Then include it in `group by` & same with `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a full query:

```
select i.accountnumber,
       sum(i.saleamount) as sale_amount, sum(r.returnamount) as return_amount,
       (case when sum(i.saleamount) = sum(r.returnamount) then 1 else 0 end) as full_return_flag
from [idtable] i left join
     [returntable] r
     on r.id = i.id
group by i.accountnumber;
```

`status` is not in the result set so I don't think it is needed in the query.  But you can include it both in the `select` and `group by` if you need it.